# SQL Server : scenario with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and learning. Ive encountered a problem. Here is the scenario of my problem.

There are 2 tables, one is `Addresses` and the other is `Members`.

Previously, I got 2 columns collecting dates for `Addresses`, one for month and the other is for year.

But recently we decided to add another 2 columns to collect this date format (mm/dd/yyyy), but instead of inserting another data. I would like to use the old data from the 2 old date columns which is the month and year. And use the identifying `ID` from the `Members` table and `Address` table which is G1, G2, G3. This identifying `ID` is the primary key.

I decided to do it manually but I realized that we got a tons of data and it will take forever to finish if I do it one by one. Any idea how will I do this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

So basically it should look like this.

- Month Column = June
- Year Column = 2015
- FullDate Column = 06/01/2015

All G1 should be like this

Comment: I guess you want to update the table and set the date column to be something like `datefromparts(yearcol, monthcol, 1)`?

Comment: Assuming SQL 2012+

Comment: Yes , something like that. The data are too many. Before I insert it manually like insert into("1/1/2011"), any idea how will I make a loop. And use the 2 old columns as a reference for month/01/year

Comment: Just do an update. e.g. `UPDATE mytable SET mydatecol = DATEFROMPARTS(myyearcol, mymonthcol, 1);` you may or may not need to add a where condition if you dont want to update the column if it already has an entry (e.g. `where mydatecol is null`)

Comment: Date and Month is nvarchar. I got this error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AUG' to data type int."

Answer (score 0):

Given a table like

```
create table dbo.Addresses
(
    MonthColumn varchar(30),
    YearColumn int
)
```

you could add a computed column to the table. Since you have the month as a name, your best bet is probably going to be to just concatenate the date as a string and then convert it to a date (note, if it were an integer, you could use `dateadd()` or, if you're running SQL 2012 or more recent, `datefromparts()`

```
alter table dbo.addresses
add MonthYear as convert(date, '01 ' + MonthColumn + ' ' + cast(YearColumn as char(4)), 106) -- 106 is the mask for "dd mon yyyy"
```

This does rely on the months being standard datenames. Again, if you're able to store the months as ints, life gets easier. But as is, this is how I'd approach it.

Comment: Date and month is nvarchar. And If I replaced the ' ' to / will it turn to be dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: No. The format you have to get it in is entirey dependent upon the number in the last argument of the function. The different masks can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql. Since you're forced to use a name of a month, you kinda have to pick one that has `mon` in the mask. I picked 106 arbitrarily, but you could have also gone with 107 (or another with `mon` in there)